# Displaying status of capslock/numlock

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, numlock

I have an ASUS G56JK laptop and it doesn't have an LED indicator for the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key. Does anyone know of a program that will run on Ubuntu 14.04 and simply display the status of the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keys, either next to the clock or briefly on the screen like Logitech does on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I run Kubuntu 14.04 and the package gkrellm-leds (available directly in Synaptic) works fine for me. You can set a bunch of system monitors, but if you just want numlock/capslock, you'll have a little three-Led monitor in your screen.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Pablo, I tried this program. It displays a lot of information about the system, but I do not really need them. I shall try again and see if I can keep only the led display.

Comment: You can configure it in order to have just the 3 Leds you're interested in, I have already done it ;)

Comment: yes it works ! It is now very discreetly displaying the calendar and the led status. Amazingly, we can also control the capslock/numlocks by clicking on the corresponding led with the mouse. And there are over 190 themes for the display.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, there is a Lock Keys Gnome Extension. It displays Numlock & Capslock status on the panel. The link to the extension is [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/36/lock-keys/).